Django TypeError: Cannot filter against a non-conditional expression while filtering by foreign key
I've looked through multiple similar questions, but couldn't get the logic, and my manipulations were unsuccessful.
I have a forum app, its structure is "forum->subforum->topic->comments", corresponding models for subforums, topics and comments. I have to implement a filter on each subforum page (where the list of corresponding topics is displayed), by which I can configure the search of/among the topics by several conditions.
Particularly I have to implement a custom filter, and my idea was to create a filter for empty topics, that is, for topics only with initial comments and without responses. Through a desperate struggle I've finally understood how to implement reversed foreign key connection in querysets, but now I can't use a queryset expression as a filter, as it returns TypeError: Cannot filter against a non-conditional expression.
Here are the specifics:
filters.py:
import django_filters
from django.db.models import Count

from forum.models import Topic


class TopicFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date_span = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(field_name='created', label='Период создания')
    comments = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='comment__content', lookup_expr='icontains', label='Комментарии')
    subject = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Тема обсуждения')
    creator = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='creator__username', lookup_expr='icontains', label='Создатель темы')
    is_empty = django_filters.BooleanFilter(method='filter_empty', label='Темы без комментариев')

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['subject', 'creator', 'date_span', 'comments', 'is_empty']

    def filter_empty(self, queryset, value):
        comment_count_gte_1 = Topic.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).filter(comment_count__gte=1)
        comment_count_lt_1 = Topic.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).filter(comment_count__lt=1)
        if value is True:
            return queryset.filter(comment_count_lt_1)
        elif value is False:
            return queryset.filter(comment_count_gte_1)
        else:
            return queryset

The aforementioned approach doesn't work - apparently, one can't provide a link of queryset expression as a filter criteria. But even if to enter the expression itself, that is:
def filter_empty(self, queryset, value):
        if value is True:
            return queryset.filter(Topic.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).filter(comment_count__lt=1))
        elif value is False:
            return queryset.filter(Topic.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).filter(comment_count__gte=1))
        else:
            return queryset

then it doesn't work either.
Comparing it the way like:
def filter_empty(self, queryset, value):
        comment_count = Topic.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments'))

        if value is True:
            return queryset.filter(comment_count < 1)
        elif value is False:
            return queryset.filter(comment_count >= 1)
        else:
            return queryset

returned another error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'QuerySet' and 'int'.
And now I have difficulties in elaborating a proper filter expression for a potential queryset. Thus I came here to ask for help and advice.
If any additional info/files are necessary, I'm ready to provide them.

You .filter(…) [Django-doc] on an .annotate(…) [Django-doc] with:
def filter_empty(self, queryset, name, value):
    queryset = Topic.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments'))

    if value is True:
        return queryset.filter(comment_count__lt=1)
    elif value is False:
        return queryset.filter(comment_count__gte=1)
    else:
        return queryset

Aga, So, I thought, "queryset" is something that comes from outside (e.g., some search query from forms), and in Your version "queryset" is filter criteria itself. Okay, that wasn't obvious for me. As well as preservation of comment_count variable. Thank you very much (I hope I got You right).

I will accept this answer as the solution, though I can't check it, as another error arises (TopicFilter.filter_empty() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given).

@TiimeIrre: you forgot the name parameter: def filter_empty(self, queryset, name, value):

YAS, that works (kind of, at least it doesn't return an error anymore, others are the problems with my templates, it seems).
If I haven't pissed You off yet, could you please explain, where does this "name" parameter come from?

@TiimeIrre: it is the signature of a function you use as method=.., it is the name of the field, since it can (seldomly) happen that two fields use the same method.

Aha, so, in the latter case this parameter specifies the field that method will work with. Interesting, thank You once again.
